# filter for the field-value in the expression (kind of wrong way round)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am automatically sorting out emails based on a filter; the filter criterias are in a SQL-table. Up to know this works perfect, but only if the mail-adress of the Sender is exactly as in the sql-table.

Some mail-senders use different mail-adresses on every mail, but always have parts of the mail-adress being the same ("@abc.com").

Therefore I only but "@abc.com" into the SQL-table as criteria, and from Access this SQL-Statement works like a charm:

```
SELECT MA_Index, beding_body, beding_subj, aktion, FROM Mail_Automatik _ 
where (empfaenger = 'name_recipient' AND 'noreply-4689756@abc.com' like '*'&absender&'*');
```

But my code is talking directly to the sql-Server, and there it does not accept the part:

```
 like '*'&absender&'*'
```

now i also tried

```
LIKE '*' + absender + '*'
```

now there is no errof found anymore, but there is also no result (where there should be one)

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about your set up. But certainly you should replace `&` with `+` for T-Sql string concatenation. i.e. it should be like `'*' + absender + '*'`

Comment: thanks - see my edit above, now no error but also no result.

Comment: Sorry it should be `'%' + absender + '%'`, my bad. Didn't notice `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `+` for T-Sql string concatenation and '%' as the wildcard character to match any.

Try this (if you are passing inline sql):

```
like '%' + absender + '%'
```

It would be better if you use a parameterised query to avoid sql injection attacks rather than passing variables directly into sql server. Specially if those variables are user typed values.

for a parameterised query:

```
"Select ... Where empfaenger = @name_recipient AND @email like '%' + absender + '%'"
```

and then add those parameters (`@name_recipient` and `@email`) to the command object.

Comment: +1, although I don't think the `absender` thing is a parameter. Rather the parameter is what's to the left of the `LIKE`, and `absender` is probably just a column being searched, as far as I can see.

Comment: thanks for the string and your comments; this is used in a outlook-vba-code without user-interaction. Therefore I think to do it that way is ok; also i have no clue how to put a Parameter into the code, so I am quite happy this is up & running. And absender is the column Name, which is tested against the sender's email-adress.